# Does "faul" Refer to Laziness or Procrastination?

Tags: meaning

My question comes from the proverb: "Morgen, morgen, nur nicht heute, sagen alle faulen Leute."

One implication is that lazy people don't want to do anything at ANY time.

Another is that even hardworking person might say, "Morgen, morgen, nur hicht heute," regarding a particular, unpleasant task, which would be procrastination. Or is there one word for "lazy" and another for "procrastination?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"faul" is pretty much a 100% translation of lazy. It does not have a separate procrastinatory meaning.

The proverb refers to lazy peoples' habit of promising to do something "tomorrow" even though in the end, they *never* do it. Even though the same words might be used by a very busy person too, *faul* relates to laziness only.

Comment: I don't agree. "Prokrastination" only became a fashionable word in Germany over the last years. Before, there wouldn't be any difference made between "lazy" and "procrastinating". It both would have been expressed with "faul".

Comment: @ladybug but Tom's question is whether "faul" has a "verschieben" meaning that is *not* connected to laziness, like when a very busy person postpones something to tomorrow. To which the answer is "no". Do you not agree?

Comment: @ladybug: I agree with Pekka. And I wouldn't say _Prokrastination_ in German; I'm not sure how many people would understand it.

Comment: ah, I see. Then I didn't understand the question right, sorry. @Hendrik Vogt: yes, I guess it only became popular in some rather "intellectual" magazins as a "fun fact"...

Answer (score 7):

Note that faul has two possible meanings:

- lazy (people)
- rotten (banana)

Comment: I am a software developer for a German company. My colleagues, when something is not working, say: Da ist was faul.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from lazy another meaning of *"faul"* is translated by *"foul"* for rotten organic material.

That would also be the origin of *"faul"* when used for people - *"Faule Leute"* wait so long for their work to be done until they are rotten.